# Letters button on keywords stopped working in Windows 11 suddenly

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, windows-11, wireless-keyboard

This is the most weird things happening to me. every day for sometime my ***keyboard Alphabet, numbers and space bar will stop working*** but still functions keys like enter, control, alt and shift is working fine.

And most weird thing during it, is my letter which are not working suddenly everywhere will still work in Gmail search bar

[image]

To fix this problem, i always login my Gmail account and type in the search bar 5-10 time and then type somewhere and it fixed.

This is not new to me. i am facing this issues over 3 months and in windows 10 too (before Windows 11 upgrade)

I searched lot on google and have no solution founded.

**The Troubleshoot step i followed :**

1. Uninstalling, Reinstalling and upgrading of driver
2. Using different keyboard (hardware)
3. Running commends like `sfc /scannow` , `chkdsk` and `dism restorehealth` in windows terminal/CMD

None of these fixed my issues and i am irriated from my life. Even just 5 minute  before it happened again and did same Gmail trick to resolve this and writting this question.

I am not sure is this happening to me only or somewhere facing similar issues. I am not sure it due to hardware, Operating system or due to some software. I have checked my whole pc and i do not have any application which is suspicious.

*Note: I have wireless keyboard*

Similar problem as my : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/keyboard-letters-and-numbers-suddenly-and/520f0852-508f-4e68-a1d8-539b346e9612

Comment: First test would be a wired keyboard. That would eliminate so many things in one quick test.

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Already tried but no solution